# Upper central series of finite $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a nilpotent group of class $c$ and $1=Z_{0}(G)<Z_1(G)<Z_2(G)...Z_c(G)=G$ be upper central series of $G$. I know that nilpotency class of $G/Z_i(G)=c-i$. How can i show this fact.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you a hint.

**Lemma** Let $i$ and $j$ be positive integers. Then $Z_i(G/Z_j(G))=Z_{i+j}(G)/Z_j(G)$.

Assume you have proved this, then it follows that $Z_{c-i}(G/Z_i(G))=Z_c(G)/Z_i(G)=G/Z_i(G)$, that is $G/Z_i(G)$ has nilpotency class $\leq c-i$. But the lemma also tells you that the nilpotency class cannot be smaller, since $G$ has nilpotency class $c$.